# encoding string into json not working as expected

Tags: python, json

I am using below code to encode a string (after variable replacement) to json , but the final json coming as an Invalid json.

```
data = '''{
    "firstName": "%s",
    "lastName": "%s",
    "dept": ["IT"]
    }'''

v_data = data % ('rob','bob')

with open("new_file.json", 'w') as file:
    json.dump(v_data, file)
```

The content of the json file "new_file.json" shows as Invalid json.

Comment: You should just `file.write(v_data)` as `v_data` is already a JSON encoded string.

Comment: I didn't found any problem The json is valid on evey validators. 
`"{\n    \"firstName\": \"rob\",\n    \"lastName\": \"bob\",\n    \"dept\": [\"IT\"]\n    }"`

Comment: [Python `json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) takes a Python dictionary, not a string. You could use `v2_data = json.loads(v_data)` which would return a dictionary `{'firstName': 'rob', 'lastName': 'bob', 'dept': ['IT']}`, that you can then use with `json.dump` with `v2_data` the dictionary, or just start with a dictionary, instead of a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json.dump` changes a json to a string, while it is already a string, use:

```
data = '''{
    "firstName": "%s",
    "lastName": "%s",
    "dept": ["IT"]
    }'''

v_data = data % ('rob','bob')

with open("new_file.json", 'w') as file:
    file.write(v_data)
```